# Javascript to determine if the class contains a string in its name

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I have the following html code generated using R shiny collapsible boxes:

```
<div class="box box-info collapsed-box">
           <div class="box-header">
                     <h3 class="box-title">
                              <div style="display: block; width: 74%; ">1. Governance framework</div>
                     </h3>
                     <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
                                             <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                    </div>
           </div>
           <div class="box-body" id="idtolocate" style="display: block;">
           </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a javascript which should return TRUE if the string `collapsed-box` is contained in the first div class that i need to locate using the `idtolocate` id.

This is my try, but it doesn't work unfortunately:

```
function isCollapsed() {
   alert($('#idtolocate').closest('.box').classList.contains('collapsed-box'))
}
```

Comment: `jQuery` does not expose native properties such as `classList`.  You have to either `.get(0)` or `[0]` to break out of the jQuery object before using classList, or use the `prop('classList')` method.

Comment: You should be seeing a console error about "cannot call contains on undefined object" or something, telling you where the problem is.

Comment: I think the title of your question might be misleading - are you looking to match the full class name, or where a class name contains a string but is not equal to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.classList` is a property of native DOM elements. If you want to use that method, extract the DOM element from the jQuery collection first:

```
$('#idtolocate').closest('.box')[0].classList.contains('collapsed-box')
```

Or select the element with DOM methods instead of jQuery to start with:

```
document.querySelector('#idtolocate').closest('.box').classList.contains('collapsed-box')
```